# VB.NET-MYSQL , ERROR the connection is already open

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hola buenas tardes a todos, recurro por encima vez a ustedes en busca de ayuda, orientación...tengo una función que se encarga de buscar un dato en la *Base de Datos* en `MySQL`, si encuentra ese dato, me carga los valores en controles del formulario(txtbox, lables, etc), y en el caso de que no encuentre el datos, me da la posibilidad de elegir si quiero ingresarlo o no (mediante un messagebox con dos botones, uno aceptar el otro cancelar).

La búsqueda me funciona bien, pero cuando quiero registrar un nuevo dato (que se que no tengo) me arroja un error:

> the connection is already open

El código de la función es el siguiente

```vb
 Public Sub buscarRut()

    conexionMYSQL = New MySqlConnection

    conexionMYSQL.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;User Id=soporte;database=db_incidencias_muniquel;password=123")

    conexionMYSQL.Open()

    Try
        'conexionMYSQL.Open()

        Dim confirmacion As DialogResult

        Dim queryBusqueda As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_funcionario_soporte WHERE rut_Funcionario=@rut_funcionario"

        comando = New MySqlCommand(queryBusqueda, conexionMYSQL)

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut_funcionario", txtRut.Text)

        da.SelectCommand = comando

        da.Fill(dt)

        If (dt.Rows.Count <> 0) Then
            cmdEliminar.Enabled = True
            cmdActualizar.Enabled = True
            Button5.Enabled = False
            Button1.Enabled = False
            txtNombre.Text = dt.Rows(0)(4).ToString
            txtIdDpto.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            cmbDepartamento.SelectedItem = dt.Rows(0)(5).ToString
            'cmbDepartamento.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            'txtIdProfesion.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            ComboBox1.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            txtDireccion.Text = dt.Rows(0)(6).ToString
            txtCelular.Text = dt.Rows(0)(7).ToString
            txtAnexo.Text = dt.Rows(0)(8).ToString
            txtEmail.Text = dt.Rows(0)(9).ToString
            txtcontraseña.Text = dt.Rows(0)(10).ToString
            TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2).ToString
            'cmbTipoPermiso.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0)(6).ToString

            lblBuscador.Visible = False

            desbloquearEdicion()

            'conexionMYSQL.Close()
        Else
            confirmacion = MessageBox.Show("Rut no Existe en la Base de Datos ¿Desea Registrarlo Ahora?", "Sistema de Gestión de Incidencias", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            If confirmacion = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                conexionMYSQL.Open()
                Try

                    txtIdDpto.Text = "44"

                    'TextBox1.Text = "0"

                    'conexionMYSQL.Open()

                    desbloqearControles()

                    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_funcionario_soporte(id_departamento, nivel_acceso, rut_funcionario, nombre_funcionario, profesion, direccion, celular, anexo, email, password)VALUES(@id_departamento,@nivel_acceso,@rut_funcionario,@nombre_funcionario,@profesion,@direccion,@celular,@anexo,@email,@password)"


                    comando = New MySqlCommand(query, conexionMYSQL)

                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_departamento", txtIdDpto.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nivel_acceso", TextBox1.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut_funcionario", txtRut.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_funcionario", txtNombre.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", txtCelular.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anexo", txtAnexo.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text)
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtcontraseña.Text)

                    dr = comando.ExecuteReader

                    'MENSAJE DE CONFIRMACION
                    MsgBox("CUENTA DE FUNCIONARIO DE SOPORTE/ASISTENCIA CREADA CON EXITO")

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Finally
                    conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
                End Try
            ElseIf confirmacion = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
                conexionMYSQL.Close()
                txtRut.Text = ""
                txtRut.Focus()
                Return
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Agradezco a todos desde ya su tiempo y sus comentarios.

Answer (score 2):

El error es evidente y se explica solo: Tienes la conexión abierta cuando intentas volver a abrirla.

La tercera línea de tu método es la siguiente:

```
conexionMYSQL.Open()
```

Lo cual abre la conexión. Posteriormente,en la parte del `Else`, tienes:

```
If confirmacion = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
   conexionMYSQL.Open()
```

así que vuelves a intentar abrir la conexion y te lanza la excepción. Simplemente con que comentes la tercera línea del código te debe funcionar correctamente.

P.D. Estás utilizando un `DataAdapter` para leer los datos. Ten en cuenta que éstos no necesitan que abras previamente la conexión para usarlos. `DataAdapater` se encarga automáticamente de abrir y cerrar la conexión.

Comment: tienes razón estimado, me estaba pasando la conexión 2 veces, gracias por el comentario...aprovecho de consultarte, en esta misma función, si se encuentra un registro, carga los datos a diferentes controles, or ejemplo (txtIdDpto.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString), pero con el combobox no me funciona, estoy usando este: cmbDepartamento.SelectedItem = dt.Rows(0)(5).ToString

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid me alegro de que te funcione. En cuanto a tu otra duda,debes realizar una nueva pregunta,ya que no tiene nada que ver con esta. En [es.so] las preguntas deben ser unicas y concretas. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias estimado no estaba al tanto de lo anterior, agradezco mucho tu tiempo y tu ayuda....